# Connecting a monitor to a USB-A port

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I was thinking of buying a two-portable monitor setup for my notebook. The setups available use HDMI and USB-C connections.

The problem is that my notebook (a DELL G3 from 2019) doesn't have a USB-C port or a display port; it only has one HDMI.

One of the companies told me that they could send me a USB-C/USB-A adapter.

Question #1: Is it possible to send the video signal to a normal USB-A port and use it effectively to connect to a monitor?
Question #2: How could I connect two monitors to my old notebook?

Regards,

Camps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question #1: Is it possible to send the video signal to a normal USB-A port and use it effectively to connect to a monitor?

No. Most (all?) monitors that accept video via USB-C use [DP Alt Mode](https://www.benq.eu/en-eu/knowledge-center/knowledge/usb-c-introduction-what-is-dp-alt-mode.html), which is DisplayPort over a USB-C physical interface.

However, [DisplayLink](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics) makes graphic cards that connects over USB3, which may be used on a USB3 port to run an external display. I've not seen any monitors with this integrated however.

> Question #2: How could I connect two monitors to my old notebook?

Depending on the notebook I'd say there's the following possibilities:

- Use only one external monitor (HDMI)
- DisplayLink device
- Docking station interface